# What happens if you run “npm init” twice on same folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, init

I understand the command initialises a package.json file in the CWD, I’m just curious what happens behind the scenes if the package.json file already exists.

I couldn’t find it in documentation and didn’t notice anything different when I ran it. Does the code stop once it detects a package.json file to stop overwriting what’s already there?

I'm just trying to learn more about the inner workings of this command.

Comment: try it, run the command and u'll see

Comment: exactly, try it. if you'd like to rollback, use git to commit your code before trying something (even, the other stuffs). Reset back to the latest version when after trying.

Answer (score 2):

Running 'npm init' will just reinitialize the package.json based on the new inputs you perform. Therefore, you're doing basically the same you did when first calling 'npm init'

See the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) for more information about creating a package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `npm init` twice then it's update the package.json file as per your new init data you enter in last npm init call.

see this,

[image]

now npm init again

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will run through and overwrite the Stuff you can edit with npm init. The rest stays untouched.